# Polymer: How to test "on-tap" in mocha?

Tags: polymer, mocha.js, sinon

I have a component that when tapped on mobile, it hides an overlay and shows a description (like a hover does on desktop).

So far for desktop I've been testing mouse events such as `mouseenter` on my components by using `myElement.fire("mouseenter")`:

```
      test('it shows the description on hover', function() {
        var actionCardOverlay = missionCard.querySelector('ct-action-card-overlay');
        var actionCardDescription = missionCard.querySelector('ct-action-card-description');
        actionCardOverlay.fire("mouseenter");
        expect(actionCardDescription.hidden).to.equal(false);
      });
```

However when trying to test mobile, it doesn't look like my `tap` events are firing in my tests when I do something like `myElement.fire("tap")`:

```
      suite('when user is using a mobile device', function() {
        test('it shows the description on tap', function() {
          var actionCardOverlay = missionCard.querySelector('ct-action-card-overlay');
          var actionCardDescription = missionCard.querySelector('ct-action-card-description');
          actionCardOverlay.fire("tap");
          expect(actionCardDescription.hidden).to.equal(false);
        });

        test('it hides the overlay on tap', function() {
          var actionCardOverlay = missionCard.querySelector('ct-action-card-overlay');
          var actionCardDescription = missionCard.querySelector('ct-action-card-description');
          actionCardOverlay.fire("tap");
          expect(actionCardOverlay.hidden).to.equal(true);
        });
      });
```

Here's a simplified version of my code in JSFiddle. I've also verified that the demo works on mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnws78cb/1/

What event would I fire? In other words, how would I simulate a tap on the element?

I'm using these test frameworks:

```
"chai": "^3.2.0",
"mocha": "^2.2.5",
"sinon": "^1.15.4",
"sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
"supertest": "^1.0.1",
"web-component-tester": "^3.4.2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom event instance

```
myElement.fire(new CustomEvent('tap'));
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter! Where does CustomEvent come from? And do I need to add that because "tap" was created by polymer and not native to Browsers?

Comment: All events produced by Polymer are CustomEvent  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

Comment: P.S. I had to change `fire` to `dispatchEvent` and it worked! One weird thing is that the event it returned was weird and doesn't look like the events I get when I use a desktop browser and mobile browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258991/polymer-how-to-distinguish-between-finger-tap-or-mouse-click-for-on-tap