# Polymer: How to distinguish between finger tap or mouse click for "on-tap"?

Tags: polymer

I have an element that has hover state (overlay). On desktop this works fine, however since there is no such thing as a `mouseenter`, I am making it so that tapping the overlay will show the other div. Therefore, I don't want the `on-tap` handler to get called when I tap on the element on my desktop.

**On my iPhone device when I tap on the element, this is what I get back:**

[image]

**On my desktop browser I get this:**

[image]

**In my mocha tests, I get something completely different when I call `actionCardOverlay.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tap'));`. Notice how there isn't even a detail for this one:**

[image]

So my question is: How can I tell if a tap event is coming from a mouseclick or finger tap? If there is no way to distinguish between the two, then is there something other than `on-tap` that I can use that is mobile specific?

Comment: have you tried something like this: `<button on-click="onClick">Tap me!</button>`

Comment: but i only want it for mobile, and not desktop

Comment: oops, my bad, you can try using `touchstart`, `touchmove` & `touchend` events.

Comment: as @Ankit mentioned, if you want to only use tap you should use the browsers touch events, the purpose of polymer's events is to unify touch and click events so you don't really need to use them if you only need an specific set of them